# SQL Server LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 table:
1. Material with the fields: materialcode, materialname, materialgroup
2. ProductionOrder with the fields: materialcode, qty, orderdate
I want to get and group by materialgroup. So, I use the following query:

```
SELECT Material.materialgroup, ProductionOrder.qty
FROM ProductionOrder LEFT OUTER JOIN Material
ON ProductionOrder.materialcode=Material.materialcode
WHERE ProductionOrder.orderdate='2013-11-30'
GROUP BY Material.materialgroup
ORDER BY Material.materialgroup
```

But the result is not correct. It take all materialcode with the materialgroup null.
Note: there are some Material in the ProductionOrder do not have the materialgroup in table Material.
The result, sometimes is correct, sometimes no.

Anyone help.
Thanks.

LVD

Comment: And what would the `correct` result be?

Comment: That's what outer join is meant to do. Perhaps you wanted an inner join

Comment: as a side note this will fail on SQL-Server (which was the tag) because ProductionOrder.qty is not part of a group by or aggregate function. (Maybe it's really MySQL?)

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you use LEFT INNER JOIN or just JOIN.

Comment: What would the output of a `LEFT INNER JOIN` be?

Comment: There's no such thing as a LEFT *INNER* JOIN

Comment: With the inner join you got all results, that match the ON-statement. So you got all Orders, that got a material set, which has a entry in the Materialtable.

Comment: In the manual for MySql you can found the syntax for inner join. But nobody write this, because its similiar with just join. 
Her is the  [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html).

Comment: A fair few dbms will accept Left and Right before inner join, suspect lazy programmer, or management disappearing the refactoring budget....

Answer (score 0):

`LEFT JOIN` Will give you all the rows from ProductionOrder  and matching rows from Material

```
SELECT Material.materialgroup, ProductionOrder.qty
FROM ProductionOrder LEFT OUTER JOIN Material
ON ProductionOrder.materialcode=Material.materialcode
WHERE ProductionOrder.orderdate='2013-11-30'
GROUP BY Material.materialgroup
ORDER BY Material.materialgroup
```

To get only the matching rows from both table try this with `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT Material.materialgroup, ProductionOrder.qty
FROM ProductionOrder INNER JOIN Material
ON ProductionOrder.materialcode=Material.materialcode
WHERE ProductionOrder.orderdate='2013-11-30'
GROUP BY Material.materialgroup
ORDER BY Material.materialgroup
```

If you want to get all the rows from Material and only the matching rows from ProductionOrder you can use `RIGHT JOIN` like this...

```
SELECT Material.materialgroup, ProductionOrder.qty
FROM ProductionOrder RIGHT JOIN Material
ON ProductionOrder.materialcode=Material.materialcode
WHERE ProductionOrder.orderdate='2013-11-30'
GROUP BY Material.materialgroup
ORDER BY Material.materialgroup
```